# Automatically reload page in Chrome without plugin

Tags: google-chrome

Using the TabMixPlus plugin for Firefox or Chrome, I can right click a page and choose "reload every..." and I could choose an interval.

I'd prefer not to install a plugin unless I really have to, and I am aware that you can type *special* things into Chrome's address bar.

This makes me think that something like this typed straight into the address might work:

```
javascript:setInterval(window.location.reload(), 2000); //2 secs`
```

I haven't managed it yet, but still don't want to rule it out as a possibility.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why are you against a plugin?  If you are that worried just write your own plugin that does exactly what you want.

Comment: I'm not against plugins, sorry if it reads like that.  I'd just like to learn a bit more about Chrome's address bar's capabilities :)

Comment: Why haven't you tried typing this into the address bar?

Comment: The problem is that once you call `location.reload()` and the page reloads, as far as Chrome is concerned it's basically like loading a new page and the context is all new (the things you typed previously are lost). So you need to persist your code somehow and have the page be the same, which is why the iframe solution of the answer.

Comment: I've tried 3 plugins to do this and all require the permission to "read and change all your data on the websites that you visit". Without reviewing source code I'm not keen!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After 6 years I have a solution for this!

The answer is inspired by the other answers here.

Edub's answer didn't work for me, it reloaded the page over and over, and didn't observe `setInterval`'s duration parameter.  I don't understand why Edub's answer doesn't work as expected.

This works for me in Chrome 67:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = "<iframe id=\"testFrame\" src=\""+window.location.toString()+"\" style=\"position: absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%;\"><\/iframe>";reloadTimer = setInterval(function(){ document.getElementById("testFrame").src=document.getElementById("testFrame").src },10000)
```

Formatted version:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = 
"<iframe id=\"testFrame\" 
        src=\"" + window.location.toString() + "\" 
      style=\"position: absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%;\">
<\/iframe>";
reloadTimer = setInterval(
    function(){ 
        document.getElementById("testFrame").src=document.getElementById("testFrame").src
    },
    10000
)
```

This works by replacing the current document body with an iframe pointing to the window's current location.

Then a call to setInterval is made, that makes the page reload on a timer.

This works well as a bookmark. setInterval's complementary function can be called by bookmark too: `javascript:clearTimer(reloadTimer)`

Notes:

- Some sites detect they are being accessed via iframe and attempt to prevent access (Stack sites for instance!)
- Browsers strip the prefix `javascript:` when pasting into the address bar so it has to be entered manually.  However `javascript:` is not stripped if entered via bookmark.

Comment: Damn, it works a treat! Nice going! And good on you for solving your own problem.

Comment: Thanks, Jon! Slight modification to use this directly in the DevTools console: `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML=
\`<iframe id="testFrame" src=""+window.location.toString()+"" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%;">
</iframe>\`; setInterval(()=>{document.getElementById("testFrame").src=document.getElementById("testFrame").src},10000);`

Answer (score 13):

You could do it through the Chrome Developer Tools using key combination **<kbd>ctrl+shift+j</kbd>**. Load the page you want, say for example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_frame.asp then hit **<kbd>ctrl+shift+j</kbd>** to open the developer tools. Right click on the body tag and select edit as html replace the inner contents (leaving the  tag and closing  tags intact) with the following:

> `<iframe id="testFrame" src="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_frame.asp" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%;" onload="setInterval(document.getElementById('testFrame').contentWindow.location.reload(), 10000);"></iframe>`

to stop editing as html you can either hit <kbd>esc</kbd> or click on one of the tags outside of the one you're editing. The page should start reloading every 10 seconds, you can close the developers tools if you'd like and it will continue to refresh, no plugin needed :)

Comment: Thanks Justin, this works so I have upvoted, but it's not the answer I was looking for so will leave the question open in hope :) Also, F12 non?

Answer (score 5):

Taking the solution from Justin Buser one step further lead me to:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = "<iframe id=\"testFrame\" src=\""+window.location.toString()+"\" style=\"position: absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%;\" onload=\"setInterval(document.getElementById(\'testFrame\').contentWindow.location.reload(), 10000);\"><\/iframe>"
```

The idea to embed the site in an iframe to be able to reload it works fine (i guess). I just wrote some code to get the body elment and replace the innerhtml with an Iframe to the current url.

This way it is possible to bookmark some JavaScript code and fire it at any site to reload it. Hope it helps.