# How do I auto-refresh a tab without downloading anything?

Tags: refresh

How do I auto-refresh a tab (just that tab) without downloading any extension or anything? I have a chrome OS. I really need to do this, but I don't know how. Also, if you're going to answer this question, please give me simple instructions. I don't know a lot about computers so if the instructions aren't simple, I probably won't understand.

Comment: What software? What OS? There are web browsers with tabs, text editors with tabs, media players,… If you need this in a browser and your browser does not support such functionality out of the box, will you consider changing to one that does? Note that you cannot refresh a website without downloading at least some header (that may tell the browser the site hasn't changed since), so "without downloading *anything*" cannot be fulfilled. Please [edit] the question and add details.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping I could do it without editing anything because this chromebook doesn't belong to me. Also, I edited the question like you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in, I assume, your Google Chrome tabs. It does require some programming type activities, at least the way I know of. Rather than steal credit from another, here is the link to the page where I found an answer for you.

[Automatically reload page in Chrome without plugin](https://superuser.com/questions/436227/automatically-reload-page-in-chrome-without-plugin)

If you do not feel comfortable doing that, a plugin is your only way to go. Short of building a machine to hit the f5 key over and over again.